# DICOM fail to use c-move : Move Request Failed: 0006:0317 Peer aborted Association (or never connected)

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I am running the following command with the find-SCU tool from the OFFIS DICOM toolkit (dcmtk):

```
movescu -k 0010,0020="PAT004"  ip_adress 104 -aec serverAET -aet myAET --study -ll debug -od data
```

And I keep getting the error.

The association seem to have worked well but the actual c-move seems to fail at the moment of the transfer
 [message of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l2Nj.png)

Comment: The actual command contains a valid ip adress, I just didn't want to give it away. And, as I said, the association is done correctly. The problem occurs at the copying step.

Answer (score 4):

The screenshot tells that you can successfully establish the connection, but the server aborts after receiving the request.

You missed to specify the mandatory key QueryRetrieveLevel (0008,0052).

add

```
-k 0008,0052="PATIENT"
```

to your command, and it should work.

However, *moving* means, that the server (MOVE-SCP) is prompted to transfer the images matched by the request to a destination application entity. This must be specified by providing the AET of that system:

```
-aem <AET of the destination>
```

This frequently fails due to one of these reasons:

- the move destination AE title is resolved to an IP-address and port. This is achieved through the C-MOVE-SCP's configuration.
- A Storage SCP has to listen for images transferred in the scope of the C-MOVE, its IP, AET and port have to match the MOVE-SCP's configuration for the Move destination AE title.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Yes, it works. I also added storescp command beforehand to make it work. Thank you.